# How to allow my user to use their own external SMTP in Yii2

Tags: api, yii2, smtp, mailgun, mailer

I have an app where I want my user to be able to add their own SMTP server, whether by Mailgun, Amazon SES, etc.

If we're taking the mailgun as an example, right now my Mailgun is set up in config/web.php like so

```
'mailgun' => [

               'class' => 'boundstate\mailgun\Mailer',
                       'key' => 'MYKEY',
                       'domain' => 'DOMAIN',

                ],
```

Then I use the following to compose an email

```
Yii::$app->mailgun->compose()->setFrom($FROM)
                                    ->setReplyTo($contest_creator_email)
                                    ->setTo($email)
                                    ->setSubject($subject_line)
                                    ->setTextBody($plaintext)
                                    ->setHtmlBody($htmlemail)
                                    ->send();
```

How would I make it so that my user could set-up his own key instead of using mine? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting mailer configuration.

Before sending email you can set mailer configuration in your api/controller.

```
//Set config value dynamicaly
        Yii::$app->set('mailer', [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'YourHostName',
                'username' => 'UserName',
                'password' => 'Password',
                'port' => 'Port',
                'encryption' => 'Encryption'
            ],
        ]);
```

And send mail as below.

```
 Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom($FROM)
                                ->setReplyTo($contest_creator_email)
                                ->setTo($email)
                                ->setSubject($subject_line)
                                ->setTextBody($plaintext)
                                ->setHtmlBody($htmlemail)
                                ->send();
```

Comment: Yes,for any host you can set host and all other parameters :)